# How do I get past these bubbles without dying in The Army level?

Tags: bleed

The best I've been able to do is just throw myself at it and get hit a few times before maybe getting through or maybe dying.

There has to be a better way.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main trick is to get the area as clear as possible first, and then dash through it.  Try shooting for a bit to clear out most of the bubbles, then dash across the top while shooting down to keep any more from coming up.  It should look something like this.

[image: Getting past the bubbles]

This principle can also be applied to sections with falling rocks, just dash towards the bottom instead.

---

There's another sequence just before the image you posted where you have to jump down a taller shaft against the flow of bubbles.  For stuff like that, you generally want to shoot straight down, and use dashes to keep yourself from falling too quickly.

[image: The taller shaft]